# Can I use ROI Pooling to extract region features from a feature map of the entire image in any task?

Tags: conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, roi

Is ROI pooling (e.g. in Pytorch) suitable for any tasks instead of object detection?
For example, a pre-trained VGG16 on ImageNet. I use this image [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5xoC.jpg) as the input with the size of 640*640, and I will get a feature map with a size of 40*40 after the last convolutional layer.  Assume that I already have the bounding box of the cat, shown in the red rectangle. **Can I use the known bounding box to extract the features of the cat with ROI Pooling directly?**